# How to compiler OpenMP program using clang?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, compiler, clang

My gcc compiles well, but clang fails with the following message:

```
clang -fopenmp=libomp -o main main.c
main.c:5:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
```

I also installed `libomp5` package and changed flag to `-fopenmp=libomp5` , though it didn't help either:

```
clang -fopenmp=libomp5 -o main main.c
clang: error: unsupported argument 'libomp5' to option 'fopenmp='
clang: error: unsupported argument 'libomp5' to option 'fopenmp='
```

[these](https://clang-omp.github.io/) recommendations didn't work.

Would be grateful for hints on installing necessary 16.04 specific packages and passing corresponding flags.

Comment: What version of Clang are you using? I have the same problem BTW with clang-3.8 and clang-3.9 on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: sudo apt install libomp-dev

Comment: Finally, I can use OpenMP with Clang on Ubuntu! I have wanted this for a long time!.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem.

```
sudo apt install libomp-dev
```

Fixed it with Ubuntu 16.10

```
//test.c
#include "omp.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  #pragma omp parallel
  printf("thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
}
```

Then

```
clang test.c -fopenmp
./a.out
thread 0
thread 5
thread 2
thread 1
thread 7
thread 3
thread 4
thread 6
```

Also

```
clant-3.9 test.c -fopenmp
```

works.

---

GCC and Clang use different OpenMP runtime libraries : libgomp and libomp respectivly.

Clang's runtime is the [LLVM OpenMP](http://openmp.llvm.org/) runtime which in turn is based on the Intel OpenMP runtime (which is open source).
https://www.openmprtl.org/

On my system GCC installed `omp.h` at

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include/omp.h
```

and `libomp-dev` insalled `omp.h` at

```
/usr/include/omp.h
```

These are different header files which include different function definitions. It may be okay to use either header file for e.g. `omp_get_wtime()` but in general I think it's probably better to use the header file that corresponds to the runtime that is linked to.

Comment: Worked on vanilla 16.04 with stock clang in repos.

Comment: I justed installed Ubuntu 17.04 which defaults to Clang 4.0. I stilled had to use `sudo apt install libomp.dev`.

Comment: If you accidentally link libgomp from clang 6, your code will be silently serialized.

Comment: `clant-3.9 test.c -fopenmp` shoud be `clang-3.9 test.c -fopenmp`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems *omp.h* file doesn't exist in your system **PATH**. firstly try to locate *omp.h* file if you don't know where it is:

```
find / -name 'omp.h' -type f
```

And then run this command to compile your code:

```
clang -o main main.c -I/path/to/omp/folder
```

Comment: That does not fix the problem. It still can't find `omp.h`.

Comment: Did you find any **omp.h** in your system? can you append output of these commands to your question?

Comment: `*.h` are header files, why would he want to add them into his path? they should be in `/usr/include` for example.

Comment: Thanks Ghasem,  libomp-dev installation on 16.04 solved.

Comment: `-I /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/include/` breaks compilation with clang because it picks GCC's other headers over the standard headers clang normally uses, e.g. for `immintrin.h`.  And even using `-idirafter`, it's not compatible with the use of `__attribute__` declarations, errors such as: `omp.h:308:45: error: '__malloc__' attribute takes no arguments
  __GOMP_NOTHROW __attribute__((__malloc__, __malloc__ (omp_free),`